# pain of browser back button

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there any way using JavaScript(or something else) to detect/prevent that user clicked on browser back/forward button ?

I would like to know about the common practice to deal with this issue. This is really pain especially in the work flow like ordering.

Comment: The good (not necessarily common) practice is to make sure that your application actually works, even when faced with a user that uses his browser as it's designed.

Comment: This has to be one of the most-duplicated questions on SO. I'm surprised none of the five people answering it remembers seeing this question ten times or so.

Comment: @John: nope, I'm only a member for a month or so. I can see there are several related questions to the right...

Comment: Thanks all for responding. Sorry for redundant question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a one page web app (meaning a single page is loaded, then all changes are done dynamically in that page with Javascript) you have options:

When the user clicks the back button, you leave the page, since it's the only one, and you can warn the user through the event [window.onbeforeunload](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

And then, if you need/want more control of the back/next button behaviour, you can add a hash( # ) key to handle that.
See my answer to that question: [Change the get parameters in the address bar in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258719)

Answer (score 12):

Actually preventing the user from using the back or forward button is bad usability and will frustrate users a lot - to be blunt, it's passing a developer problem back to the user.

I think the [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), coupled with `window.onbeforeunload` in javascript (like SO uses) would be really useful for your circumstances.

Comment: It's actually `window.onbeforeunload` (I just made this typo myself).

Answer (score 3):

look into a history manager. something like this:

http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/

you can make the back button actually do something useful, like going back to previous (valid) state, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nope this is not possible, you can not usurp the *browsing experience* from a user, but hope there should be a work around to this....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, not, but you can use the `window.onbeforeunload` event to warn users not to go away, when risking data loss. Please bear in mind this doesn't work on Opera.