# Browser navigation, back button issue

Tags: browser, ie8-browser-mode

I want to know how you guys deal with back button issues in your web applications.

I can not forbid users to click back button on their browser, but when they hit it, the page code doesn't run. So writing in `page_load()` makes no sense.

I have searched online and found this link: [Disabling Back button on the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87422/disabling-back-button-on-the-browser). It does not work for me. Any idea?

Comment: You can't disable it. Just like I can't disable your close buttons (well, with IE it's questionable).

Comment: I suggest you start with one of the answers already given to this same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336134/pain-of-browser-back-button

Comment: Don't do this. Websites that try to do this are terrible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable the back button. You can try to open your page/form in a new window so there would be nothing to navigate back to
Normally, If I have a critical or lengthy form, I tend to maintain a dirty-flag and if the user starts entering something, the dirty-flag gets set and on save or submit it gets reset. You can use [`unload/beforeunload`](http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/02/06/Difference-between-javascript-OnUnload-VS-OnBeforeUnload-Events.aspx) javascript event to see if the dirty-flag is set and ask for confirmation.